# Use Infragistics.WPF.Excel in Blazor .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, infragistics, typeloadexception

It may be not the right thing to do, but ... i have a 3rd party library (Infragistics) that provides functionality to create and read Excel files. I need to use this from within a Blazor application. Unfortunately this 3rd party dll references something from WPF i guess...

```
TypeLoadException: Counld not load type 'System.Windows.Size' from assembly 'WindowsBase, V4.0...'
```

Question is: What do i need to search for in NuGet to get the WindowsBase Assembly into my Core 3.1 Blazor application?

Comment: This remark from the Infragistics site: _To try the latest updated Blazor Preview bits, you can grab them from Nuget here_ - [https://www.nuget.org/packages/Infragistics.blazor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Infragistics.blazor). Try to install this package from Nuget. May be it will help to resolve your problem. 
Actually the `WindowsBase.dll` is included to the .NET Framework.

Comment: i don't use infragistics.blazor but infragistics WPF stuff. Why? Because of the wonderful xlsx functionality which is not included in blazor components currently...

Comment: The `WindowsBase.dll` part of .NET Framework. But your  `WindowsBase.dll` not including 'System.Windows.Size' type for some reason. Try to locate the `WindowsBase.dll`. Then you can use `View in object Browser` in the Visual Studio to check is it contain 'System.Windows.Size' type or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Infragistics package "IgniteUI.Blazor.Documents.Excel" instead of "Infragistics.WPF.Excel" solves the problem for me.